# PowerShell: Get membership info for a computer account (not a user account)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

Getting an ambiguous identity error.  I can search successfully to return the group that a user account is a member of, but when I try to search for the groups that a computer account is a member of there is the ambiguous identity error.  I tried to use a -type or -identity switch, but either I did not have the syntax correct or it was just not applicable.

Where my targeted computer account is called SNA00760856, I have been working on using...

```
Get-QADGroup -Containsindirectmember SNA00760856
```

Any massaging that I can do to the command to get the groups that the computer SNA00760856 is a member of?  Dropping in a user account in place of the computer account works like a charm.

I have also tried to qualify the computer name with the domain info.
Ie SNA00760856.mydivision.mydomain.com or mydivision\SNA00760856

Also tried to collect the membership of the computer using which I know is wrong after a closer reading of the switch info....

```
Get-QADobject -IndirectMemberOf SNA00760856
```

Results in ambiguous identity as well.

Comment: Have you tried the DN?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to clean up the output, use this

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership (Get-ADComputer ComputerName) | select-object name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the group memberships of a computer in AD through the ActiveDirectory module with `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`. You'll need to search via the computers DistinguishedName, which can be achieved by leveraging `Get-ADComputer`:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership (Get-ADComputer SNA00760856).DistinguishedName
```

That'll return all of the group objects `SNA00760856` is a member of.

Answer (score 1):

If you export to a list use

> Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership ( Get-ADComputer XXXXXXX ) | Out-File C:\XXX\XXX

Answer (score 0):

I used something to pull down the AD Computer information and the Computer membership into one Text file.
This is using `$Env:computerName` to get the name of computer script is run on. If you want to select a different computer, change out the variable `$HostName =`  to a computer name of your choice. Example `$HostName = "Janes-Laptop01"` .
The computer you run this script on must have the `Active Directory` module installed for this to work.

```
Import-module -Name ActiveDirectory
$HostName = $Env:computerName
$path = "c:\temp\Computer_AD_Membership_Info_$($HostName)_$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd-hhmm).txt"
Echo "`r`n ******* Computer OU Information. *******  `r`n" | Out-File -FilePath $path -Encoding utf8 -Force ;
Get-AdComputer -Identity $($HostName) -Properties * | Out-File -FilePath $path -Encoding utf8 -Append -Force ;
Echo "`r`n ******* AD Groups Computer Member of. ******* `r`n" | Out-File -FilePath $path -Encoding utf8 -Append -Force ;
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership (Get-ADComputer $($HostName)).DistinguishedName | Out-File -FilePath $path -Encoding utf8 -Append -Force ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a one liner; just replace `$comp` with the computer name, or define it as part of your script:

```
((Get-ADComputer $comp -properties memberof).MemberOf | get-adgroup).name
```